# Predicates in coredata in objectivec

Tags: ios, core-data, predicates

I have two tables in coredata Details and person.
Person has two fields Id and Code:

Id        Code
IAS       RT
IAS       TP
IAS       IP

Now,detailshas two fields,code and Name

Code     Name
RT       Rataz
TP       Tranzps
IP        Irrz

Now I want to use predicates so that i can first fetch the id from person,then after getting the field against the id.I can use the same id as predicate to get Name from person table.How this can be achieved.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Person has two field id and code... person has two fields code and name... That's really confusing. Could you show a screen shot of your core data model file? The one where you create the entities and attributes etc... I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, how you should do this is using a relationship.

Add a relationship to `Person` called "details" and add a relationship to `Detail` called "people" (or "person" if it's singular).

Now you can get the person by the id and then use `person.details` to get the details associated with that person.

Core Data is not a database. Think of it more as a data model. Create the data model and object relationships that you need and use them.

You would be better off checking out a core data tutorial. It will help you in understanding how to use core data.